# How to prevent spam on Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a very simply commenting system in my app.
I want at least 5 seconds delay between comments from same user in order to prevent spam, and here is the structure of `Realtime Database`:

UID - Unique ID

```json
"comments" : {
    "postUID" : {
      "randomCommentUID" : {
        "dateCreated" : number (epoch format),
        "text" : string,
        "user" : string (UserUID),
        "replies" : {
          "randomReplyUID" : {
            "dateCreated" : number (epoch format),
            "text" : string,
            "user" : string (UserUID),
            "votes" : {
              [UserUID: string] : number (in [-1;1] range)
            }
          }
        },
        "votes" : {
          [UserUID: string] : number (in [-1;1] range)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm thinking of finding the last comment user created and checking the `dateCreated`, but I'm unsure how to achieve such in Realtime Database rules

Comment: You can either write Security Rules or use Cloud Functions.

Comment: Have you found any way to fix this yet? Mind showing an example of how you detected that a message was send less than 5 seconds ago? Thanks

Comment: I haven't found a solution. Ended up believing in customers (in production haha). It's small project anyways.. I'm afraid of scaling my project as I get more users, also concluded that firebase is ONLY adequate for small projects....